# emu8086 can't print numbers on emulator screen

Tags: assembly, emulation, x86-16

i'm trying to display the result of multiplying two numbers on the emulator screen of emu8086, when i use small 8 bits numbers, the result is printed fine when i run the code, but with 16bits numbers i get 0 on the emulator screen, i'm not sure it something is wrong with my code or the emulator it self, i'm totally new to assembly, and i've been trying to solve it for the past hour, that's my code

```
    include 'emu8086.inc' 
    name "multiply_two_16_bit_numbers"

    org 100h

    mov ax, 512   ; 
    mov bx, 512   ;

    mul bx 

    call print_num

    ret
    DEFINE_PRINT_NUM
    DEFINE_PRINT_NUM_UNS
    end
```

hope you guys could help me please, thanks.

Comment: You haven't shown us the code for `print_num`.

Comment: @Michael i'm not sure i understand you right, but i used [call print_num

    ret
    DEFINE_PRINT_NUM
    DEFINE_PRINT_NUM_UNS] function

Answer (score 1):

Note that 512*512=262144=40000h, which is a 32 bit number with the low 16 bits being zero and that's presumably what you get printed. This form of the `mul` instruction puts the top 16 bits of the result into register `dx`, you should find 4 there. If you want to print the whole result, you will of course need a 32 bit printing function, and you'll have to pass the arguments properly.

Comment: thanks for your reply, would you elaborate it a little more please, what's the 32 bit printing function, and how to pass the arguments properly.

Comment: i understand that print_num function prints numbers in AX, so what's the function to print the numbers in DX